# Is there a name for sum over one set divided by the cardinality of another set?

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory, summation, terminology

What is the summation of one set real numbers divided by the cardinality of another set called?
$$A \subset\mathbb  R$$
$$\frac{\sum A}{|B|}$$

I will try and be specific to my problem because I lack the skill to properly define the relationship between the *A* and *B* sets.

*A* is a set that contains the dollar figure of invoices to our marketing department for their  advertising.

*B* is a set that is the sales leads/interactions that are a result of the marketing purchases.

The aim is to tie an average dollar figure to each sales lead based on the total marketing spend and the volume of leads produced.

As an example, *A* may contain 2 elements with attributed dollar values of \$100 and \$40, at that time there are 70 elements within the *B* set; I expect the result to be $2.

Comment: There is no particular meaning to this operation unless the sets are somehow related. Are they?

Comment: If there is I am not sure how to define it. Should I be specific to my problem? This is my first question in this SE so I am not entirely sure on protocol... and I can't math good.

Comment: I'm sure that without additional details there won't be a useful answer. So if you want to describe the relation of two sets somehow, it can't hurt.

Comment: Fair enough. I will try and do that. I think I answered my own question though. Is it just some sort of arithmetic mean?

Comment: You probably don't mean that $A$ is a *set*, since you probably want to count multiple invoices even if they have the same dollar amount, and a set can't do that. You could let $A$ be a *sequence* or a *multiset* or even a *discrete measure*. But I'm being pedantic... could you please give a simple example?

Comment: I would not call it a mean of any kind unless the sets have equal cardinality.

Comment: Ah well to be specific the elements of the 'set' *A* are objects that contain at least a dollar value of the invoice, the date and time of the invoice and a unique identifier. I am looking to find the summation of the dollar value for all elements in the set.

Comment: After the edit: this could be called advertising cost per interaction. A common example is "cost per click". There is no need for mathematical terminology to express this. The closest math term may be _ratio_, which refers to dividing something by something...

Comment: Yeah, that is almost exactly what I called it. I was looking for the appropriate notation for the result of the type of calculation. This should help. If this is answered as 'ratio' I will just tick it off.

Comment: ...Okay I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ratio you dope!

See the definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio).